# Full list of MessagEase commands

Tags: keyboard, messagease-keyboard

Yesterday I started using MessagEase and I love the concept. However it seems there are a lot of ways to use different gestures. Is there a full list of all gestures and commands of MessagEase?

Answer (score 3):

All commends and settings of MessagEase are documented on the app itself. Please run the app and consult the "How to" section, or send us an email support at exideas dot com if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to access the MessagEase UI is actually through the keyboard itself: just press and hold down this key...
[image: hand symbol]

There are multiple How-To sections, an FAQ, and additional advanced instructions or settings.  Admittedly, it can be a challenge to parse through all the pages to find what you're looking for, and there doesn't (to my knowledge) appear to be any centralized compendium of all the gestures and commands available (there *is* something for all the symbols).  If you've tried but can't seem to find how to do something in particular, their support staff is very friendly and have answered back to my e-mail inquiries within 24-hours on the occasions that I reached out to them (whereas the Facebook community got 0 replies).